# How to enable hugepages on eks cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks, huge-pages, karpenter

How to deploy hugepages in EKS aws cluster? Ideally, managed nodes using Karpenter. Can't find any docs anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You can configure hugepages for your OS by customizing the node template's userData. If you change the settings after the kubelet is running, don't forget to restart the kubelet. The new limits should display when you describe the node. See https://www.clyso.com/blog/kubernetes-worker-node-with-hugepages/.

Comment: Please see the "Provide context for links" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
The link you posted is now broken, and because you didn't provide sufficient information about _how_ "You can configure hugepages for your OS by customizing the node template's userData" your answer is no longer helpful